# Application hangs/freezes when setting RadGridView datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgrid, radgridview

I have one winforms app and when I minimize the window I need that the processes still running. It's all ok until i set the RadGrid datasource :  `radGrid1.DataSource = datasource1;`
When I set the datasource this way the app just freezes and nothing happens more. 
After some search I've modified the code to:
`radGrid1.BeginUpdate();
radGrid1.DataSource = datasource1;`
and this way I can set the data source but my grid loses the format.
If I add the `radGrid1.EndUpdate()` it freezes too.

What can I do do load the datasource and don't lose the format of my radgrid?

Best regards

Comment: Do you have any formatting event like e.g. `CellFormatting`? What format does your grid lose exactly?

Comment: Can you upload a small sample demonstrating the issue somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the telerik docs](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/populating-with-data/tips-when-binding-to-custom-collections):

> To prevent the grid from traversing all data fields in that collection, set the GridViewTemplate.AutoGenerateColumns property to False. In this case, the additional fields that you might use when sorting, grouping, etc., should be included in the MasterGridViewTemplate.Columns collection. With these settings, only the properties that are used as column FieldName properties or those specified in the MasterGridViewTemplate.Columns will be extracted.

Should fix the problem you described with "losing the format". 
Second problem, the program freezing, is not something I've encountered in the numerous of occasions I've worked with `RadGridViews` in windows forms environments.

The only thing I can think of is that your datasource collection is too large, or items in the collection have too many fields that the `RadGridView` is trying to generate columns for  when the `AutoGenerateColumns` property is set to `true`.

Comment: my collection has 20 rows only, it should be a fluid process... setting AutoGenerateColumns to false didn't solve the problem. I can't figure it out. When I'm debugging the app just hangs when the datasource is setted... thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this problem today in an app using Telerik RadGridView 2017.2.613.40. I had columns defined in code:

```
 _grid.Columns.AddRange(
            //...more columns
            new GridViewCheckBoxColumn
            {
                Name = "IsSmallLabel",
                FieldName = "IsSmallLabel",
                MinWidth = 100,
                MaxWidth = 100,
                IsVisible = true,
                ReadOnly = false,
                HeaderText = "Small label"
            },
            new GridViewCheckBoxColumn
            {
                Name = "IsTechCard",
                FieldName = "IsTechCard",
                MinWidth = 100,
                MaxWidth = 100,
                IsVisible = true,
                ReadOnly = false,
                HeaderText = "Tech card"
            });
```

And an OnCellFormatting event:

```
    private void OnCellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var checkCell = e.CellElement as GridCheckBoxCellElement;

            if (checkCell == null) return;

            var poItem = e.Row.DataBoundItem as PurchaseOrderItem;

            if (poItem == null) return;

            if (string.Equals(e.Column.Name, "IsSmallLabel", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                checkCell.Visibility = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(poItem.LotNo) ? ElementVisibility.Visible : ElementVisibility.Collapsed;
                checkCell.Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(poItem.LotNo);
            }
            else if (string.Equals(e.Column.Name, "IsTechCard", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                checkCell.Visibility = poItem.TechnologyCard != null ? ElementVisibility.Visible : ElementVisibility.Collapsed;
                checkCell.Value = poItem.TechnologyCard != null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

The two fields were actually missing from the model and adding them solved the problem with the app hanging. The issue seemed to be related to the formatting function as removing it would also stop the app from hanging.